# Does this passage have a lydian sound?

Tags: harmony

The music sources is *[Album national russe](https://imslp.org/wiki/Album_national_russe_(K%C3%B6hler%2C_Louis)) (Köhler, Louis)*, and the particular passage is...

[image]

...before saying the music is in `G` major and there isn't any `C#` to make lydian, hear me out. The basic voice leading for `I6 IV` would have voice leading of `^5 ^6`, and if the line to the `^6` was a descent it would use a lowered seventh, like these...

[image]

If the lowered seventh version were tonicized to `C` the line would become `^5 ^4 ^3`. So, the point I'm getting at is the `^7` is raised rather than the typical lowered. It's even emphasized as an accented passing tone. The `F#` is played above a bass/root `C` for an augmented fourth.

I would think from a jazz perspective that `C` chord would be labelled not as plain `Csus4` but something like `C(#4)`. Of course the style of this music isn't jazz, but it seems to me that augmented fourth (keep in mind it's not resolving like a dominant tritone to `B-G`, `C` is the chord root) is the source of the lydian sound. My understanding is common practice *avoided* that sound by *lowering* the `^7`. The fact that it isn't lowered, and is accented, makes me think the passage could be described as having a lydian sound, lydian tonality. Even if it is for only a brief passage.

Comment: Why wouldn't "basic" voice leading for I6-IV involve ^5-^4 and more than 3 voices (so SATB can get ^5-^4, ^1-^6, ^1-^1, and ^3-^4 respectively)?

Comment: I don't really see this: it's "lydian" just as much as any passage on the fourh grade that uses the leading tone, but besides that there's no modulation, it's just a passage from I to IV, the melodic movement is in the tonality, and I don't see using the lowered seventh as mandatory in this case; yes, it's in the downbeat, but it's also very short and used almost like an appoggiatura.

Comment: There is a difference in how classical analysis and jazz analysis think about modes, and I think your question falls in that crack.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, the SATB voice leading you gave is essentially the `V65/IV IV` I gave but without the motion through the `^7`. That just avoids the whole point of my question regarding `^7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @Dekkadeci's correct analysis ...

OP mentions a "jazz context". So let's imagine this song being played by a jazz group with a soloist improvising over the chord changes.

The expected "arrangement" of measures 9–13 would be `G | C | D | G` without alterations. Jazz musicians would recognize that the entire passage is in the key of G, and that the C chord is not changing the tonality. Thus, the soloist (and accompanying instruments) would play F#, not because the chord needs alteration or any reference to Lydian, but because G major has F# in it.

Certainly, heard in isolation, there is a Lydian-ish sound, but this is incidental and would not be considered analytically significant. Said another way: **the measure is Lydian-ish, but the passage as a whole is not.**

An equivalent question would be to ask if measure 11 has a Mixolydian sound, since there is a C natural against what is otherwise a D major chord. And in a jazz context, many musicians would use a Mixolydian scale in that measure, but analytically there's no change of mode.

---

It's also worth noting that the melody itself is an elaborated, descending G major scale:

[image: Melody reduction showing G-F#-E-D-C-B]

Answer (score 2):

If you analyze the passage as if it tonicizes C major instead of remaining in G major, then you can say that the passage has a Lydian sound. F♯ does turn the C major scale into the C Lydian scale, after all.

Do note that every bar in the passage except for the highlighted Bars 9-10 and the similar Bars 13-14 make claiming that Bars 9-10 tonicize C major (the IV chord) a hard sell, as Bars 1-8 keep up a G-D double pedal on the first beats of those bars, and Bars 11-12 and Bars 15-16 can both be harmonically analyzed as V-I in G major, inversions and nonchord tones notwithstanding. Bars 15-16 cadence at a repeat and an assumed phrase ending to boot, making a sell that the passage drifts away from G major at any point even harder.